# How to run tests in current test project only

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

How to run every test in current project only?

I do not see any option to do this in any menu or context menu.

Playlist is a static list; I'm still in the process of adding tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked too soon. Select Project in drop down, then select project in list, right choose run selected tests.

I'll keep the question up. Maybe will help someone else.

[image]